# ValueError: y_true takes value in {'True', 'False'} and pos_label is not specified in ROC_curve

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision, sklearn-pandas

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=2)

# generate a no skill prediction (majority class)
ns_probs = [0 for _ in range(len(y_test))]

# fit a model
model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 3)
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

# predict probabilities
lr_probs = model.predict_proba(x_test)

# keep probabilities for the positive outcome only
lr_probs = lr_probs[:, 1]

# calculate scores
ns_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, ns_probs)
lr_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, lr_probs)

# summarize scores
print('No Skill: ROC AUC=%.3f' % (ns_auc))
print('Logistic: ROC AUC=%.3f' % (lr_auc))

# calculate roc curves
ns_fpr, ns_tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, ns_probs) <-- Error Occurred
lr_fpr, lr_tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, lr_probs)

...
```

I'm trying to use the ROC curve in the KNN algorithm.

```
ValueError: y_true takes value in {'True', 'False'} and pos_label is not specified: 
either make y_true take value in {0, 1} or {-1, 1} or pass pos_label explicitly
```

However, as you can see above, an error occurred.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(data.Malware)
data['TrueorFalse'] = encoder.transform(data['TrueorFalse'])
data.value_counts(data['TrueorFalse'].values, sort=False)
data.head()
```

So to solve this problem, I thought the labels I wrote "True" and "False" were problematic because they were strings. Therefore, the above code was applied to switch True or Flase to 0 and 1, respectively, but errors still occur. I'm using `True` and `False` as labels in the `TrueorFalse` column. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing 2 arguments in your function, pass an additional parameter stating the `pos_label` just like the error states while elaborating.

In your case, instead of passing the arguments in function like:

```
ns_fpr, ns_tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, ns_probs)
```

try like:

```
ns_fpr, ns_tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, ns_probs, pos_label=1)
```

for both of the curves. Hence the suggested modification will be:

```
ns_fpr, ns_tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, ns_probs, pos_label=1)
lr_fpr, lr_tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, lr_probs, pos_label=1)
```

Hope this might resolve your error completely!

Answer (score 0):

```
y_test = y_test.map({'True': 1, 'False': 0}).astype(int)
```

Adding this code helped me to solve my problem.